# Implicit pattern definition binds no variables when using underscore as identifier

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a code like the following:

```
implicit val _ = new MyClass()
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Implicit pattern definition binds no variables
```

Why?

I am using Scala -> 2.13.3, SBT -> 1.3.13, and Java -> OpenJDK v14.0.2

Comment: Related [Create unnamed implicit class or function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758131/create-unnamed-implicit-class-or-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8699

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11618

> If a pattern definition binds no variables, it is
> probably a mistake if it is marked implicit,
> because it introduces no implicit values,
> or if it is a template statement, because
> it accidentally introduces a template member.

> Please warn on:
>
> ```
> implicit val _ = 42
> implicitly[Int]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

In Scala 3 (Dotty) we could provide unnamed implicit value like so

```
scala> class MyClass(val x: Int)
// defined class MyClass

scala> given MyClass(41)
// defined object given_MyClass

scala> summon[MyClass].x + 1
val res0: Int = 42
```